# Is there any way to make GetX navigation to use cupertino page route instead of material page route

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I want my app to have that iOS smooth slide in/push in page transition, and I was able to achieve that when I use the native Navigation API provided by flutter, the only thing I should do is to pass a CupertinoPageRoute instead of a MaterialPageRoute, but as you all know, the syntax for the native navigation API is a but verbose, and I prefer using GetX navigation in my app since it's easy to read but with GetX I couldn't find a way to force the use of CupertinoPageRoute.

So my question is: Is there any way to achieve the behavior I talked about above using GetX?

What I tried:
the traditional way

```dart
/// rest of code
   onTap :  () => Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => NewScreen())),
/// rest of code
```

for iOS style

```dart
/// rest of code
   onTap : () => Navigator.of(context).push(CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (_) => NewScreen())),
/// rest of code
```

using GetX

```dart
/// rest of code
   onTap : () => Get.to(() => NewScreen()),
/// rest of code
```

The problem here with GetX is that I get the desired behavior but only when on iOS device but not on Android device, and I do get the wanted results using the `CupertinoPageRoute` but my question again is achieving a transition similar to Cupertino Style on Android but using GetX.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. My question wasn't whether I should use GetX or not, it was about finding a way to achieve the behaviour I'm looking for using GetX, if you could help with that it would much appreciate.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [get_x_navigation_generator package](https://pub.dev/packages/get_x_navigation_generator), it says that you can

> Generates a method to go to each route (customizable navigation method) with arguments

Comment: Hi there, I will definetly check it out.